# Find the gcd of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

This is for a modern algebra course.

Find the greatest common divisor of each of the following pairs of $p(x)$ an $q(x)$ of polynomials.  If $d(x)=gcd(p(x),q(x))$, find two polynomials $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ such that $a(x)p(x)+b(x)q(x)=d(x)$.

a. $p(x)=7x^3+6x^2-8x+4$ and $q(x)=x^3+x-2$ where $p(x),q(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$

1st attempt:

I used an online factoring calculator to try to factor $p(x)=7x^3+6x^2-8x+4$ and it told me it's not factorable (I am not really sure how to factor polynomials with cubic terms easily by hand). and since $p(X)$ is not a multiple of $7q(x)=7x^3+7x-14$ I think maybe $gcd((p(x),q(x))=1$ in this case?

$$d(x)=a(x)p(x)+b(x)q(x)$$
$$1=a(x)(7x^3+6x^2-8x+4)+b(x)(x^3+x-2)$$
$$1=7x^3a(x)+6x^2a(x)-8xa(x)+4a(x)+x^3b(x)+x-2b(x)$$
$$1=x^3(7a(x)+b(x))+6x^2a(x)-8xa(x)+(4a(x)-2b(x))$$

Kind of got stuck here...

b. $p(x)=x^3+x^2-x+1$ and $q(x)=x^3+x-1$ where $p(x),q(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$

1st attempt: I also can't seem to factor either of these...

I'm so confused..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just as for integers, the Extended Euclidean Algorithm can be used to compute the Bezout identity for the gcd. [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) for a convenient version of the algorithm.

Comment: I guess your question is wrong. Both $x-1$ and $x^2+x+2$ are not factors of $p$.

Comment: @MonkeyKing you're right there was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, to obtain $a(x)$  and $b(x)$ ,you have to use the *Extended Euclidean algorithm*, exactly as in $\mathbf Z$.

In $\mathbf Q[x]$, this leads to polynomials having coefficients with a large number of digits. So there exists a normalised form of the algorithm, in which the successive remainders are *monic*  polynomials,which makes divisions simpler.

The second example, in $\mathbf Z_2[x]$, is easier: $p(x)=x^3+x^2+x+1$, $q(x)=x^3+x+1$. The successive divisions are:
 \begin{align*}
x^3+x^2+x+1&=1\times(x^3+x+1)+x^2\\
x^3+x+1&=x\cdot x^2+x+1\\
x^2&=(x+1)(x+1)+1,
\end{align*}
hence $\,\gcd(p(x),q(x)=1$, and the Extended Euclidean algorithm displays as follows:
$$\begin{array}{lccc}
r_k(x)& u_k(x)&v_k(x)&Q(x)\\
\hline 
p(x)& 1&0& \\
q(x)&0&1&1\\\hline
x^2&1&1&x\\
x+1&x&x+1&x+1\\
1&x^2+x+1&x^2\end{array}$$
Thus we obtain:
$$1=(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x^2+x+1)+x^2(x^3+x) $$

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm afraid your q(x) term is missing a -1

Comment: You mean a $-2$, I suppose? We're in $\mathbf Z_2$.

Comment: Oh so maybe I am just confused. in the equation given in the book $q(x)=x^3+x-1$ but in your answer the -1 term is dropped from the original equation, so we can just do that in $Z_2$?

Comment: I took  $-2$ from your question, so there was ver little job to do. I'll change to the actual value of your book in a moment, it will be more instructive. Note that in $\mathbf Z_2$, $-1=1$.

Comment: @Math Major: Sorry, I've just founf actually I read  $-2$  from $q(x)$ in your first example! :o(

Comment: no worries! I really appreciate your explanation!